# Scala implicit parameter not found

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to write this `object`:

```
object Timed {
  def apply[T](fn: => T)(implicit logger: Logger): T =
    measureDuration(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace.last.getMethodName, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, fn, logger)
}
```

That I would like to like this (in another `class`):

```
def test(): Unit = {
  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("testTimed")
  Timed { someFunction() }
}
```

and everything seems to be in scope (same package), but I consistently get:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter logger: org.slf4j.Logger
Timed { someFunction() }
```

The only way I can get this work, is basically by not using the implicit:

```
Timed { someFunction() }(logger)
```

works - which obviously defeats the purpose.

What am I missing??

Comment: you've missed an `implicit`  keyword before `val logger`

Comment: And you could even move it into the Timed object if you prefer that.

Comment: Thanks! It works with the `implicit` before `val logger`.

Comment: Using `.last` on `Array` is a code smell

Comment: @cchantep - really? I'm not sure why? oh - the Array could be empty?

Comment: @cchantep don't see why. @Frank could be empty as you said but that does not make it a code smell. `myList.get(0)` could also fail and it's not a code smell.

Comment: @Frank he's maybe saying that because the default implementation defined on some trait may be inefficient, but I'd be surprised. I'll check that

Comment: @Frank nope, the implementation comes from `IndexedSeqOptimized` and is the following: `def last: A = if (length > 0) this(length - 1) else super.last`. I think you can safely ignore what cchantep said

Comment: In any case this is not type safe. Even if here and now there is a reasonable assumption it cannot be empty, the context can changed, so always better to use a typesafe alternative to have the compiler helper, moreover removing such code smell is not difficult.

Comment: @cchantep - how would you remove it?

Comment: In order to keep at type level/compile time there is no way to be sure of finding a method name the `Timed` should better be defined with `def apply[T](fn: => T)(implicit logger: Logger): Option[T]`, using the safe `lastOption` and `Option.map`

Comment: @cchantep - the return type of apply is not the type  of the first parameter of `measureDuration`.

Comment: Refactoring `apply(..): T` from using `.last` to `.lastOption` obviously implies having `Option[T]`

Comment: Changing the return type of `apply` is not an option given the API needed. A better (less disruptive) solution would be to plug in some sort of default value if `.lastOption` returns `None`. Also, in which cases can `getStackTrace` return an empty `Array`?

Comment: @Frank It's explicitly possible, at least: "Some virtual machines may, under some circumstances, omit one or more stack frames from the stack trace. In the extreme case, a virtual machine that has no stack trace information concerning this thread is permitted to return a zero-length array from this method."

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - thanks! So when the array is detected to be zero-length, we can plug-in e.g. `no stack trace found` or `""`. No need to change `apply`'s signature to `Option[T]`, which forces the rest of the code to deal with an `Option[T]` rather than a `T`: it's much better to have `Timed` not leave any "trace" in the execution flow. That `Option[T]` would reflect a deficiency of `Timed`, when the user would presumably be interested in the behavior of `fn` only. That `Option[T]` is not part of `fn`, so it shouldn't appear as a result of inserting `Timed`.